# Multiprocessing with elastic search in python

Tags: python, multithreading, elasticsearch

Got stuck with this problem while working with multiprocessing in python.

I have a python script that calls 7 functions in parallel. These 7 functions again call 5 functions each which are the same. These 5 child functions use `Elastic Search` to get me results back to the parent function. And from this parent function the results are given back to top most parent function. So when I call the top parent script, 35 threads are created in parallel(desired).

Now the script seems to be running in parallel and I have only one ES cluster (my PC) and one node in it. I searched a bit and understood that the node is getting locked by the first thread that is using the ES first and the next thread starts. I need more nodes in the cluster.

```
node.name: "Data one"
node.master: true
node.data: false

node.name: "Data Two"
node.master: false
node.data: true

node.name: "Data Three"
node.master: false
node.data: true
```

After I create my nodes this way, my doubt is how do I let my threads know which node to use and create indexes on that node only. Is it this way? :

```
es_client=ElasticSearch(['Node One'])   //'Node Two' 'Node Three' and so on for the rest of the threads?
```

I'm trying to figure out why the code is executing the threads one by one. Any help will be really appreciated. Am I wrong in my understanding somewhere here?.
Thanks guys for reading this long post.

EDIT: With the code format

"grandparentscript.py"

```
func_topmostscript():
    q1=Queue.queue()
    p1=Process(target=func_fieldfunction(field1,q1)).start()
    a=q1.get()
    q2=Queue.queue()
    p2=Process(target=func_fieldfunction(field2,q2)).start()
    b=q2.get()
    q3=Queue.queue()
    p3=Process(target=func_fieldfunction(field3,q3)).start()
    c=q3.get()
    q4=Queue.queue()
    p4=Process(target=func_fieldfunction(field4,q4)).start()
    d=q4.get()
    q5=Queue.queue()
    p5=Process(target=func_fieldfunction(field5,q5)).start()
    e=q5.get()
    q6=Queue.queue()
    p6=Process(target=func_fieldfunction(field6,q6)).start()
    f=q6.get()
    q7=Queue.queue()
    p7=Process(target=func_fieldfunction(field7,q7)).start()
    g=q7.get()
    //Do something with p,q,r,s,t,u,v
```

"parentscript.py"

```
func_parentscript(field,queue):
    c1=Process(target=func_child1())
    c2=Process(target=func_child2())
    c3=Process(target=func_child3())
    c4=Process(target=func_child4())
    c5=Process(target=func_child5())
    # Do something with c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 as C
    queue.put(C)
```

Each of the child function called uses an ES client and sends back the output to the parent script.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's difficult to say. For the nodes you could make a generator calling `itertools.cycle` over your list of nodes and add that to your data.

Comment: What part of the code do you need to see? So I could post it

Comment: Edit your Question accordingly to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and people can help.